# How can I correctly render GeoJSON maps using React Leaflet with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, geojson, react-leaflet

React Leaflet GeoJSON not rendering

I am genuinely confused about rendering a GeoJSON map using React Leaflet. I am currently using typescript and I have tried to import my geojson file in different ways and nothing seems to work at rending a GeoJSON map. I have correctly installed all dependencies which seemed to be a cause for some people on other stack overflows. I have been stuck for quite a while.

**I have tried to use **

#1 importing the geojson data directly

`import data from './geojsonData.geojson`

which gives me an error saying

`Cannot find module './geojsonData.geojson' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

#2 importing the json data directly
`import data from './geojsonData.json'`

which gives me an error in down the road at the

`GeoJSON data={geojsonData}` portion saying

```
Type '{ type: string; crs: { type: string; properties: { name: string; }; }; features: ({ type: string; properties: { name: string; otherName: string; someNumber: number; 

Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"FeatureCollection" | "Feature" | "Polygon" | "MultiPolygon" | "Point" | "MultiPoint" | "LineString" | "MultiLineString" | "GeometryCollection"'.`
```

#3 using fetch to get the data and update the state using useEffect

```
export async function fetchGeoJSON(filePath: string): Promise<any> {
    const response = await fetch(filePath);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

export const SeoulChoroplethMap = () => {
    const [geojsonData, setGeojsonData] = useState<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('./geo.geojson');
                console.log(response); // Log the response object to inspect its contents
                const data = await response.json();
                setGeojsonData(data);   
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error fetching GeoJSON:', error);
            }
          };
        fetchData();

    }, []);

    const style = (() => {
        return ({
            fillColor: "YlBuGn",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '2',
            fillOpacity: 0.9
        });
    });

    return (
        <MapContainer
            center={[37.541, 126.986]}
            zoom={11}
            minZoom={10}
            maxZoom={14}
            style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw' }}
            scrollWheelZoom={true}
        >
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <GeoJSON data={geojsonData} style={style} />
        </MapContainer>
    );
};
```